# How can I get all object vals and subobject vals using reflection in Scala?

Tags: scala, object, reflection, hash

I have an object that looks like this:

```
object Settings {
  final val Host = "host"
  final val Protocol = "protocol"

  object User {
    final val Name = "username"
    final val Password = "password"
  }

  object Subject {
    final val Query = "query"
    final val Predicate = "predicate"
  }
}
```

What I'd like to do is something like `membersAsHash(classOf[CollectionSettings])` and receive a hash) of all of the vals that I've declared in the object:

```
[
  Host => "host", 
  Protocol => "protocol", 
  Name => "username",
  Password => "password",
  Query => "query",
  Predicate => "predicate"
]
```

It'd be fine if the key was a string, even the full package name (e.g. com.example.Settings.User). What I really need is the values, so if I can only get that, it's still acceptable.

This has gotten me the name of the subobjects, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the vals that are internal to each:

```
val optionsToCheck = {
  import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
  val mirror = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
  val subObjects = ru.typeOf[CollectionSettings.type].declarations.filter(_.isModule)
  subobjects.map(o => mirror.reflectModule(o.asModule).instance.asInstanceOf[Object].toString).toList
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The neat thing here is that you're using *constant value definitions* (i.e., final values with no type annotation; see §4.1 of the [language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf)), so you don't even need any mirrors:

```
def deepMembers[A: scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag](a: A) = {
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

  def members(s: Symbol): Map[String, String] =
    s.typeSignature.decls.collect {
      case m: ModuleSymbol => members(m)
      case m: MethodSymbol if m.isAccessor => m.returnType match {
        case ConstantType(Constant(s: String)) => Map(m.name.decodedName.toString -> s)
        case _ => Map.empty[String, String]
      }
    }.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, String])(_ ++ _)

  members(typeOf[A].termSymbol)
}
```

It works like this:

```
scala> deepMembers(Settings) foreach println
(Name,username)
(Predicate,predicate)
(Query,query)
(Password,password)
(Protocol,protocol)
(Host,host)
```

If for some reason you couldn't use constant value definitions, you'd need to adjust the `MethodSymbol` case to work with instance mirrors,
but the basic approach to recursively collecting key-value pairs from child objects would be the same.

Comment: This was super effective. Thank you!

Comment: @TravisBrown: How can I make it work for non-final members ?

Comment: @VenkatSudheerReddyAedama Probably worth a new question—if you post one I can try to take a look this evening.

Comment: Done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324664/how-can-i-get-all-non-final-object-vals-and-subobject-vals-using-reflection-in
Thanks Travis :)